# How to retrieve bucket prefixes in a filesystem style using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

Doing something like the following:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('a_dummy_bucket')
bucket.objects.all()
```

Will return all the objects under 'a_dummy_bucket' bucket, like:

```
test1/blah/blah/afile45645.zip
test1/blah/blah/afile23411.zip
test1/blah/blah/afile23411.zip
[...] 2500 files
test2/blah/blah/afile.zip
[...] 2500 files
test3/blah/blah/afile.zip
[...] 2500 files
```

Is there any way of getting, in this case, 'test1','test2', 'test3', etc... without paginating over all results?
For reaching 'test2' I need 3 paginated calls, each one with 1000 keys to know that there is a 'test2', and then other 3 with 1000 keys to reach 'test3', and so on.

How can I get all these prefixes without paginating over all results?

Thanks

Comment: There is no way to get what you want without paginating.

Comment: No, you can't. Because  S3 is NOT typical file system in the first place. Write a script and let the it filter for you.

Comment: So having millions of files makes me iterate over all of them....

Comment: S3 documentation already mentioned it is an object store. Means you need to handle indexing or files in database or whatever. Aws does provide event trigger in S3 bucket to let you send information when some activity is done on the bucket.

Comment: Yes, I know about the triggering, but that's outside the scope of what I'm wanting to achieve. But thanks.
helloV commented this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36992225/550252 about the AWS cli that does the pagination for you. I assume that, is doing hundreds of calls when the bucket is huge, isn't it? So event them have to do it.

Comment: There is one good news : S3 object in the bucket "possible" store in sequential manner. There is a Maker parameter, yuo can use list_objects(Marker = "objectkey")  to start listing from the point that you stop. :-D

Comment: @mootmoot but what is the main difference between using this approach an a normal pagination?

Comment: If you save current last file marker somewhere, next time, you can can use it as a starting point to traverse less objects.

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean, but that wouldn't retrieve a possible new key inserted before the mark, because you are assuming there won't be changes on past pages. Anyway, this doesn't seem to have an optimal solution.

Answer (score 11):

I believe getting the [Common Prefixes](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/boto3/examples/s3.rst#list-top-level-common-prefixes-in-amazon-s3-bucket) is what you are possibly looking for. Which can be done using this example:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects')
result = paginator.paginate(Bucket='my-bucket', Delimiter='/')
for prefix in result.search('CommonPrefixes'):
    print(prefix.get('Prefix'))
```

[AWS Documentation#Bucket.Get](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html) says the following regarding Common Prefixes:

> A response can contain CommonPrefixes only if you specify a delimiter. When you do, CommonPrefixes contains all (if there are any) keys between Prefix and the next occurrence of the string specified by delimiter. In effect, CommonPrefixes lists keys that act like subdirectories in the directory specified by Prefix. For example, if prefix is notes/ and delimiter is a slash (/), in notes/summer/july, the common prefix is notes/summer/. All of the keys rolled up in a common prefix count as a single return when calculating the number of returns. See MaxKeys.
>
> Type: String
>
> Ancestor: ListBucketResult

Comment: The question specifically says `without using pagination`

Comment: Well, I'm not trying to avoid pagination, just to perform the minimum amount of call.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to escape from pagination. You can specify less than the default page size of 1000, but not more than 1000. If you think paginating and finding the prefix is messy, try the AWS CLI - which internally does all pagination for you but gives you only the results that you want.

```
aws s3 ls s3://a_dummy_bucket/
          PRE test1/
          PRE test2/
          PRE test3/
```

Comment: Well, this could work, but then I need to execute external commands from my application and parse the output.